# how to make New lines in a cell using phpexcel

Tags: php, phpexcel

i have problem with php excel,

i want to make new line in one cell but i can't, i have tried using \n or <br /> but  itsn't work. this my code:

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('H5', 'Hello\nWorld'); // i need this show in two line
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('H5')->getAlignment()->setWrapText(true);
```

fyi: my format excel is xls not xlsx.
many thanks :)

Comment: Does your actual code reference cell H5 or H%

Comment: @Mark Baker, sorry i just mistype. actually this is for cell H5. i just update my question, many thanks :)

Comment: OK, second question (seeing as you changed it when you edited): 'Hello\nWorld' or "Hello\nWorld"? Standard PHP quoting for strings applies: the double quotes make a difference to the \n

Answer (score 134, accepted):

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('H5', "Hello\nWorld");
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('H5')->getAlignment()->setWrapText(true);
```

Works for me...

You should always use [double quotes](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double) when you add escape sequences in a PHP string.

Comment: It is useful to note that if you are doing this to a cell you have created by merging other cells you should specify all of the cells by their original mapping.  Eg if you create B2 by merging B2-E6 then the argument to getStyle is 'B2:E6'

Comment: this is working in your example but i want output like Hello \n World DEMO(new line after Hello).but here two new line created so how i solve this?

Comment: yes, content must be wrapped with double-quotes.  Thank you.

Answer (score 33):

you should use 'r' to break into new line into excel with php

and use double quotes when you add escape sequences in a PHP string.

```
  $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('H5', "Hello\r World");
  $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('H5')->getAlignment()->setWrapText(true);
```

Comment: +1 for \r This should be the accepted answer. Save me the day with \r Thanks.

Comment: You might want to try PHP_EOL as the new line separator is os-specific.

Comment: pay attention to double quotes

Comment: @Ravin what about if I have data from MySQL? How will I put a new line same for $row['abc']. Can you help Thanks

Answer (score 12):

Improved answer based on Ravin and others

```
$objPHPExcel
  ->getActiveSheet()
  ->setCellValue('H5', "Hello".PHP_EOL." World");

$objPHPExcel
  ->getActiveSheet()
  ->getStyle('H5')
  ->getAlignment()
  ->setWrapText(true);
```

Comment: `PHP_EOL` is useless in this case, because it will give an EOL char based on the OS where the php script is run (so likely linux/unix server), but the file will likely be opened on Windows, where default EOL will be different.

Comment: @Muhammad what about if I have data from MySQL? Like how will I put a new line same for $row['abc']. Can you help Thanks

Answer (score 10):

We can set for the *default style*, so don't need to specify for each cell range:
`$objPHPExcel->getDefaultStyle()->getAlignment()->setWrapText(true);`

Answer (score -7):

To achieve next line but same cell forxcel export, this is the simplest solution.

```
<tr>
    <td style="wrap-text: true">
        Test
        <br />
        Test2
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: <td style="wrap-text: true">
        Test
        <br />
        Test2
    </td>
</tr>