# PHPexcel set cellspacing

Tags: php, formatting, phpexcel

When I print to pdf, my cells have some spacing between them, which I cannot get rid of.

Basically I have similar problems as this:
[How to generate a nice PDF with php Excel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13088793/how-to-generate-a-nice-pdf-with-php-excel) (see the first picture)
which is described as solved

> By setting cellspacing to 0 borders are handled almost as expected,

So I guess I need to set cellspacing to 0, it's just that I can't find out how to do that.

Update:

I found this http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/discussions/249376. But the solution involves messing with the source code of PHPexcel, I would much rather find a way to achieve this within my project, not changing the PHPexcel files..

Comment: Given that PHPExcel gives you a choice of PDF renderer, it might help if you indicated which of the supported renderers you're actually using

Answer (score 2):

See lines 1028 to 1032 of the HTML Writer. Cellspacing **is** set to 0 unless you're writing to PDF **and** getShowGridLines() for the sheet is `true` (which is the default value), in which case it's set to 1... so calling setShowGridLines(false) for the worksheet(s) before saving should set cellspacing to 0.