# Call to undefined method PHPExcel_Worksheet::getAlignment()

Tags: php, phpexcel

I've been trying to make a new line in exporting data to excel file with this code

```
if ($campaign['type'] == 'blended') {
    $objWorkSheet->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($col++, $row, "$launch_date,\n email: {$email_launch_date}, \n tm: {$tm_launch_date}");
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getAlignment()->setWrapText(true);
```

But this gives me

> Type: Error Message: Call to undefined method
>   PHPExcel_Worksheet::getAlignment()

I also try the suggestion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5960242/how-to-make-new-lines-in-a-cell-using-phpexcel) but it doesn't work for me,

what is the right thing to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be applying styles to individual cells or ranges of cells, not to worksheets (which don't have a style)

```
if ($campaign['type'] == 'blended') {
    $objWorkSheet->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($col, $row, "$launch_date,\n email: {$email_launch_date}, \n tm: {$tm_launch_date}");
    $objWorkSheet->getStyle(PHPExcel_Cell::stringFromColumnIndex($col) . $row)
        ->getAlignment()
        ->setWrapText(true);
    $col++;
}
```